# How show / hide sticky banner in sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have simple 2 column structure:

1. Content with some fullwidth div
2. Sidebar with sticky banner
   Need hide banner, when scroll to fullwidth div and after show again. My code: https://codepen.io/maxbeat/pen/eYZzWZP work only first fullwidth div, how fix it for every fullwidth div?

How fix this jQuery code for every fullwidth div:

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    var divTop = $('.fullwidth').offset().top - $('.banner').outerHeight(true) - 20;
    var divBottom = $('.fullwidth').offset().top + $('.fullwidth').outerHeight(true);

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > divTop && $(window).scrollTop() < divBottom) {
        $('.banner').addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('.banner').removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your jquery code to this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var divTop = [];
  var divBottom = [];
  $('.fullwidth').each(function(index){
      divTop[index] = $('.fullwidth').eq(index).offset().top - $('.banner').outerHeight(true) - 20;
      divBottom[index] = $('.fullwidth').eq(index).offset().top + $('.fullwidth').outerHeight(true);
  })


  for(var i = 0; i < $('.fullwidth').length; i++){
      if (($(window).scrollTop() > divTop[i] && $(window).scrollTop() < divBottom[i])) {
          $('.banner').addClass('hide');
          break;
      } else {
          $('.banner').removeClass('hide');
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: thanks, but i dont know how many fullwidth div in content

Comment: I updated the answer. It works with a loop and is not important how many div you have in your page.